# consolidate multiple pandas column based on column values into one

Tags: python, pandas

> I want to consolidate pandas column based on values of pandas column.

```
4       None     None
None    4.1      None
None    None     4.2
None    None     None
None    4.1      4.3
```

> to

```
4       
4.1     
4.2     
None        
4.1
```

Rule -
1.Get first non null value of row among all columns.

Answer (score 2):

Use back filling missing values with select first column by position:

```
df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

If `None` are strings first convert them to missing values:

```
s = df.replace('None', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
print (s)
0      4
1    4.1
2    4.2
3    NaN
4    4.1
Name: a, dtype: object
```

If need numeric values cast to floats:

```
s1 = df.replace('None', np.nan).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0].astype(float)
print (s1)
0    4.0
1    4.1
2    4.2
3    NaN
4    4.1
Name: a, dtype: float64
```